# ipad html a href to fragment omn same page not working

Tags: html, ipad, fragment, href

I have an html containing an `a` element as follows:

```
<a href="#MT564_sequence A1">
```

On the same web page I have an element

```
<td colspan="5" align="left" style="font-style:italic" class="hilite" id="MT564_sequence A1">
    <div style="margin-left: 60pt;">Start of sequence A1 - LINK</div>
</td>
```

In any browser, including Safari on pc's, this works fine: clicking the link triggers a jump to the td element.
But on my ipad the link does not work. What is possible is holding the link longer, then choose "open in new tab" which gives a new tab and a jump to the correct td element.

Why does the normal jump on the same page not work in Safari on an ipad, and what can be done about it?

Note: user agent string on Safari ipad =
`Mozilla/5.0 (Ipad; CPU OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebkit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25`

Comment: Just a guess, has some simular, but can you remove the space from the ID.

Comment: Nice guess but no luck: I replaced blank by underscore but no effect.